# Counting number of cells in a range that contain certain text characters

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

My question simply: Is it possible to generate the data in A3:A5 using a formula?

```
          A         B        C       D       E       F

1   PASSED/TOTAL |           EXAMS ATTEMPTED
2   -------------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------
3   1/3          | ✔exG  | ✖exZ  | ✖exH  |       |
4   3/4          | ✖exC  | ✔exJ  | ✔exR  | ✔exN  |
5   1/1          | ✔exW  |       |       |       |
```

*(If it's not clear, columns B through F from row 3 onward show whether someone has taken an exam AND whether they passed or failed it.)*

So, back to the question... I can easily determine the total number of exams in the 3rd row with something like this in A3:

```
=MINUS( 5, COUNTBLANK( B3:F3 ) )
```

But how can I determine the number of passed exams? Is there even a way with formulas to search text content of other cells with some sort of "contains" thing -- or maybe even regex searching? Something like this:

```
=CountCellsThatContainText( "✔", B3:F3 )
```

Assuming there is such a thing, then I would need to combine the two together -- which I also am unsure of ... maybe `CONCATENATE()` would work for that, e.g.:

```
=CONCATENATE( CountCellsThatContainText( "✔", B3:F3 ), "/", MINUS( 5, COUNTBLANK( B3:F3 ) )
```

So..... before I posted I did a little more digging and found [`QUERY()`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343) but uhhh.... I'm hoping a greater mind than mine can tell me if that's even the right direction to go in.

PS: If it would make it more do-able, we could split column A into 2 or 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following little piece of code gives you the result, without prior knowledge about the character code number.

### Code

```
function mySplit(range, delimiter) {
  var output = [], maxCol = range[0].length;
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var colCounter=0, counter=0;
    for(var j=0, jLen=range[0].length; j<jLen; j++) {
      if(range[i][j] == "") {
        colCounter++;
      } else {
        if(range[i][j].split(delimiter).length > 1) {
          counter++;
        }
      }
    }
    output.push(counter + "/" + (maxCol - colCounter));
  }  
  return output;  
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]
[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Certain Text Characters](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X68G8ICvhyVR7TbnLMs1gY8b-rCEAjLtGmTphkrdxcQ/edit?usp=sharing)**
If you copy the file, then you can access the code. Add the code into your existing sheet by going to *Tools\Script editor* in the main menu. Paste the code and save.

Comment: WOW. Had no idea you could do something like that. I'm playing with it now.

Comment: ***Brilliant!*** Thank you so much! I tweaked it a little bit and couldn't be more happy.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(--(if(B3:F3="",0,CODE(LEFT(B3:F3,1))=10004))))&"/"&minus(5,countblank(B3:F3))
```

works for your example but highly not recommended. Simple booleans (Pass/Fail, Yes/No, 1/0) would be much easier to deal with in a spreadsheet and the `ex?` do seem redundant, given the column headings.

Comment: RE *"the ex? do seem redundant, given the column headings"*: Indeed. In the actual spreadsheet there are dozens of possible exams but people only ever take 5-10 -- and not in any specific order. Also, in the actual spreadsheet there is only one **EXAMS** heading (a merged cell) above them all because I don't need a column for each specific exam.

Comment: I'm going with the custom function solution but I want to thank you for taking the time to come up with something @pnuts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution also:

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(",",B2:E2),"✖\w+",""),","))&"/"&COUNTA(B2:E2)
```